# How can I play Blu Ray discs with my MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, video, hardware, blu-ray

I'd like to buy a Macbook Pro 15 inch instead of a Dell, and I know I can send video to the HDMI TV using the Moshi adapter.

My MacBook doesn't have a drive for Blu Ray discs. Is there a way to solve this?  I kind of want the navigation of chapters and extra features in a Blu Ray disc, so if using `makemkv` and a Sony external Blu Ray drive to make the Blu Ray disc into an `.mkv` file, that's not so preferred.

(Is one possible way to use the Sony external BD drive (about $180), and use bootcamp to boot up Windows 7 instead?  Although this method is not so preferred because it needs to boot up only Windows)

Answer (score 4):

[VLC 2](http://www.videolan.org) on Mac has experiment support for BD playback. That should work with an external drive of your choice. If you don't need a native player, you can always run a VM and have your pick of Linux or Windows Blu Ray player software.

Vlc can't play decoded commercial Blu-ray discs as I know. But Macgo have got the BDA license already and can decrypt Blu-ray codes legally.