# Can I play Blu-ray discs directly on a MacBook using an external drive?

Tags: blu-ray

Is is possible to use an external drive to play Blu-ray discs on a MacBook? It has a Core2Duo processor and 9400m graphics.
does it need any software, either paid or free?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ask Different. Please use the [search](http://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=blu+ray) function before posting a question. I think [these](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54867/mac-support-for-blu-ray?rq=1) [previous](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27131/how-can-i-play-blu-ray-discs-with-my-macbook?rq=1) questions are nearly the same as yours. If the answers posted there don't help you, please [edit](http://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/162638/edit) your question to let us know why those answers are not sufficient and what problems you encounter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. VLC will play Blu-ray discs once you have installed the necessary extras. Info and links to the files you need [here](http://vlc-bluray.whoknowsmy.name/)...